# Actualizar Total Acumulado

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

Necesito actualizar el acumulado de ventas de todos los clientes en el campo accumPurchases, para lo cual intento sumar todas las facturas de cada uno y grabar este valor alli

```
UPDATE contacts 
SET 
    accumPurchases = (SELECT 
            SUM(inv_total) AS sum_of_inv_total
        FROM
            invoice_master
        WHERE
            invoice_master.inv_cntId = contacts.cnt_id)
```

pero no logro que funcione...

```
Error Code: 1048. Column 'accumPurchases' cannot be null
```

Gracias por su orientacion.

Answer (score 2):

Parece que no todos los contactos tienen una factura. Debes decidir si, en esos casos, es más conveniente que el acumulado de ventas sea nulo *(modificando las propiedades del campo para que los admita)* o si prefieres que el valor sea cero (al fin y al cabo, si no hay factura es el acumulado de ventas es cero, ¿no?).

En este último caso, puedes emplear una función tipo `ISNULL` para cambiar los `null` por ceros.

Además, hay que tener en cuenta dos cosas si la consulta se hace de esa forma:

1. No se puede historificar la tabla de facturas. Si en algú momento se decide borrar registros antiguos de esa tabla, el acumulado de ventas de los contactos disminuiría(?).
2. Es imprescindible un indice por inv_cntId en la invoice_master para que la consulta no se eternice cuado aumente el numero de registros de la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Cambiar el campo accumPurchases en la tabla para que reciba nulos implica que hay que validar el valor que nos enviala base de datos cada vez que lo solicitemos, pero realmente no es complicado y asi funciona bien.

```
ALTER TABLE `contacts` CHANGE `accumPurchases ` `accumPurchases ` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL;
```